# Why is Azure Servicebus triggering function call immedietly after message lock expiration?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have an Azure Function with a Service Bus Binding. The `Message Lock Duration` on the Service Bus topic is `3 minutes` and `Delivery Count` of `5`.

Once in a while, the function is triggered EVEN after the first trigger call completes successfully. No additional configurations are setup via `hosts.json`

I have configured Application Insights and the trace does not make sense. The first call completes in 90 seconds but the second call is triggered 3 milliseconds after the lock period on the first call expires.

How do I determine the root cause?

Comment: Since you said that host.json has not changed, are you sure that the two messages you are talking about are the same one?

Comment: Yes, The MessageId and the Invocation Timestamps are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I use the setting of your service bus subscription. But I can not reproduce your problem.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
public static void Run(string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg} started.");
    Thread.Sleep(90 * 1000);
    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg} ended.");
}
```

And the settings of my service bus subscription:

[image]

I send three messages: test1, test2, test3(At this time, the message still in the subscription.).

[image]

About 90 second later, I get:

[image]

After this, the messages have been removed.

The above is the result of the test.

Even if it is analyzed theoretically, the situation you mentioned should not appear. Your lock time is 3 minutes, so it is greater than the function running time. And you haven't changed host.json, so the entire execution should look like this:

The function obtains information based on the peek method (so the information continues to exist in the servicebus before the function ends.), and the logic is completed within your given lock time. Since host.json has not changed, the value of 'extensions.serviceBus.messageHandlerOptions.autoComplete' is 'true'. The Azure function automatically calls the complete method to complete the information when the logic is completed, and the information is removed from the servicebus.

I suspect that you have made a mistake. Are you sure that the two messages received by your function are the same? If it is, then the information you provided may not be complete, and I cannot reproduce your problem from the conditions you provided. I have written the entire execution logic of the function above.

Comment: The issue does not crop up when you process a single message or about 500 messages. I use 12000 messages. This issue presents randomly. First batch of 3000 message caused no issues. Next batch of 5000 caused the issues for about 15 messages. Repeat experiment, issue crops up in initial batch. I need to figure out how the second and subsequent calls are triggered the result in the message eventually dead-lettering.